# Python Selenium Click Image

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to Python and I want to click on the image here. I know how to click a button, but I can't do it for the image.

```
<img src="./img/icon/tema-icon-1-03.png" alt="imgAlt">
```

What I did for the button

```
login_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
```

**The part I made for the button works great**

Here is what I tried but it didn't work

```
appointment_image = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src='./img/icon/tema-icon-1-03.png')]").click()
```

Comment: Why would you want to click on an image? It wouldn't do anything...

Comment: Please add the code you have tried

Comment: When I click on the image it goes to another page but it's not a button

Comment: @YaDav MaNish Sorry, but thats not working

Comment: @OneMore can you try this  //img[contains(@src,'tema-icon-1-03.png')and @alt='imgAlt']

Comment: Sorry that didn't work either, I get this error  "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img[contains(@src,'tema-icon-1-03.png')and @alt='imgAlt']"}"

Comment: @OneMore better you share your url or Html source

Comment: @OneMore can you use explicitWait to click that might work your given Url is not working

Answer (score 1):

if this is Unique in DOM :-

```
<img src="./img/icon/tema-icon-1-03.png" alt="imgAlt">
```

you can `click` on it using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src, '/img/icon/tema') and @alt = 'imgAlt']")
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@src, '/img/icon/tema') and @alt = 'imgAlt']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```